# Button Click fires before custom validation occurs

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have this form with a custom validator, and Button. 
But, my custom Validator shows error only after button click.
This is my validator, Button and code behind.

```
   <asp:CustomValidator ID="CustomValidator1" runat="server" 
                ErrorMessage="User Name cannot be Empty!" ForeColor="Red" 
                onservervalidate="CustomValidator1_ServerValidate" 
                ControlToValidate="userNameTxt" ValidateEmptyText="True" 
                ValidationGroup="save-valid"></asp:CustomValidator>
     <asp:Button ID="saveButton" runat="server" Text="Save"   CssClass="save-button"  
      onclick="saveButton_Click" TabIndex="7" ValidationGroup="save-valid" />
```

This is my code behind.

```
     protected void CustomValidator1_ServerValidate(object source, ServerValidateEventArgs args)
    {
        if (IsUserValid(userNameTxt.Text))
        {
            CustomValidator1.ErrorMessage = "User Name cannot be Empty!";
            args.IsValid = false;

        }
        else
            args.IsValid = true;


    }

    protected void saveButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

         //This code executes regardless of CUstom Validator
    }
```

Comment: server side validation only occurs on postback, such as on a button click. If you want it to run on something other than button click then you will need to put it in another event, such as texbox_changed event (if it's the username field). You will need to ensure the AutoPostBack property on the textbox is set to 'true' as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to use client side validation.

```
<script type="text/jscript">
function textBoxControl(source,arguments){
    if(arguments.Value.length >0) //or control things (e.g. at least 6 character)
        arguments.isValid = true;
    else
        arguments.isValid = false;  
}
<script>
```

Code behind is like below.

```
<asp:TextBox ID="userNameTxt" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" />
<asp:CustomValidator ID="CustomValidator1"
        runat="server" ErrorMessage="CustomValidator" 
        onservervalidate="CustomValidator1_ServerValidate"
        ControlToValidate="userNameTxt"
        ClientValidationFunction="textBoxControl"></asp:CustomValidator>
```

Answer (score 1):

When I put the below code inside Save Button click, the problem gets solved.

```
        if (!Page.IsValid)
            return;
```